# Laravel Bootstrap Styling is not working when i remove public from the URL and when i add Public on url the styling works

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, frontend

**Master View file**

[image]

**It is when the public is in the URL**

[image]

**After removing public from URL**
[image]

the Bootstrap file is in public in Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Please include your code in the question directly. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more :)

Comment: What are you using to serve your application locally?

Comment: @Mark Which File i Include

Answer (score 1):

**open vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php**

**write "public/".$path instead of $path,**

```
function asset($path, $secure = null){
   return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}
```

**its work in your all css and js without write public in assets**

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help to you. thank you..!!! @Imbharat420

Answer (score 1):

It because of your all CSS and js is inside the public folder. add asset as below to js and css.

```
{{ asset('public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}
```

Or you can set asset url in .env file as well.

`ASSET_URL=public` in your **.env** file and run `php artisan config:cache`